# In phonegap app, the scrolling is not happening when user tries to scroll on input fields

Tags: javascript, android, ios, css, cordova

In the phonegap app, the scrolling (scrolling gestures) working as expected when user scrolls on non-editable elements. But the scrolling is not happening in the pages when user scrolls(scrolling gestures) on the input/textarea field boxes.
Do I need to add any property to allow the scrolling on input fields and textareas?

Comment: what do you mean by scrolling on input/textarea box? Do you want to scroll inside input/textarea?

Comment: No, I do not want to scroll inside the input/textarea. When I am scrolling the page that contains input/textarea, the scrolling gesture doesn't work in the input/textarea. However, if I scroll on the left or right hand edges on screen then scrolling gesture works.

Comment: I'm guessing there are either event handlers on those inputs that are interfering, or there are styles on the inputs that are interfering. Without seeing some code and styles, there's probably little we can do to help. It would also help to know what device(s) this is occurring on.

Comment: This issue is appearing on android device (I haven't yet checked on iOS). I have not attached any event listener to the input/textarea fields. I am using Mustache Template framework for UI pages.

Comment: Code sample
<pre><code>
 <div class="col-xs-12" style="text-align:center">
    <form name='profileForm' id="profilefrm">   
      <div class="row signup">
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
   <input name="fName" type="text" id="fName" placeholder="*First Name" value="{{fName}}"/>
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
   <input name="lName" type="text" id="lName" placeholder="*Last Name" value="{{lName}}"/>
 </div>...
</code></pre>